# Electron-packager "self signed certificate in certificate chain"

Tags: electron, electron-packager

So, I am trying to create an angular electron app, but since we are behind a proxy, I get the "self signed certificate in certificate chain" error if I want to use the electron-packager.
Installing the packager worked without any problems, but I cant use it. After `electron-packager . --platform=win32` I get the error.

Since I had the same problem while trying to install electron itself, I tried with the binaries, as suggested here https://github.com/electron/electron-packager/issues/190 but even when trying to use the file with the `--cache` arg, I still get the "self signed certificate in certificate chain" error.

Any ideas?